# Guided Action Using Lightning Web Components (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to create a Guided Action using a Lightning Web Component? I have the HTML already coded but whenever I go to launch my guided action, it doesn't work. I was thinking maybe I need to add a target to the XML file and I tried that but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Guided Actions use Salesforce Flows to launch. Lightning Web Components can be embedded within the Flows.

So Technically you can embed your LWC within the Flows and assign the Flow to the Guided Action.